# Error getting the amount grouped by name and account number SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue on my SQL query. I tried doing two ways

- With the first query I got the right amount but I lose some name descriptions
- With the second  I got every name descriptions but I got a lower amount.

Context: I want to get the revenue gotten between two dates.

I need the following columns from tables

- Table `reciboDet` I need the columns `CtaIngreso, ValorUnitReciboDet`
- Table `CuentaIngreso_A` the column `nombrectaingreso, ctaingreso` (only to create the join)
- Table `Recibo` the columns `FechaRecibo and ReciboAnulado`

To get the right name descriptions I need to verify the receipt year that was in the table `AvpgEnc`, but when I do that a lose the amount.

*First query*

```
SELECT        
    ReciboDet.CtaIngreso
    , SUM(ReciboDet.ValorUnitReciboDet) AS Total
    , CuentaIngreso_A.NombreCtaIngreso
FROM
    ReciboDet 
    INNER JOIN CuentaIngreso_A 
       ON ReciboDet.CtaIngreso = CuentaIngreso_A.CtaIngreso
WHERE 
    (ReciboDet.NumRecibo IN
        (SELECT  NumRecibo
          FROM   Recibo
          WHERE  (FechaRecibo BETWEEN '01/10/2020' AND '31/10/2020') 
                 AND (ReciboAnulado = 0) 
                 AND (CuentaIngreso_A.Anio = DATEPART(year, FechaRecibo))
         )
     )
GROUP BY 
    ReciboDet.CtaIngreso
    , CuentaIngreso_A.NombreCtaIngreso
ORDER BY 
    CuentaIngreso_A.NombreCtaIngreso
```

*Second query*

```
SELECT
    ReciboDet.CtaIngreso [cuenta],
    sum(ReciboDet.ValorUnitReciboDet) [monto], 
    CuentaIngreso_A.NombreCtaIngreso [descripcion]
FROM 
    ReciboDet
    inner join avpgenc 
        on ReciboDet.NumFactura = AvPgEnc.NumAvPg
    inner join CuentaIngreso_A 
        on ReciboDet.CtaIngreso = CuentaIngreso_A.CtaIngreso
WHERE 
    (ReciboDet.NumRecibo IN
        (SELECT  NumRecibo
         FROM    Recibo
         WHERE   (FechaRecibo BETWEEN '01/10/2020' AND '31/10/2020') 
                 AND (ReciboAnulado = 0)
         )   
     AND (year(AvPgEnc.FechaVenceAvPg) = CuentaIngreso_A.Anio)
    )
GROUP BY 
    ReciboDet.CtaIngreso
    , CuentaIngreso_A.NombreCtaIngreso 
ORDER BY 
    ReciboDet.CtaIngreso
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Also please reformat your queries so they're readable without horizontal scrolling (e.g. put keywords and separate columns on their own line).